# How can i set product custom options by observer event(checkout_cart_after_add_product) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Below code i am doing.

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
$price = 100;
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify it?

Comment: you can set $item->setOptionname($optionname);

Comment: $item->setColor('red');

not working.

Comment: @klict

above code working with custom price properly but i also need to set custom options of product which is already created from admin.

Comment: Okay this is a bit difficult to explain but your answer lies with :
    $item->getProductOptions()->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomOptions();
Now you have access to options you searched for and you can set the value you want

Comment: @klict ...  Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Post option's value from product detail page, you  can set that value like below code.

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $post = $this->_request->getParams(); 

        $associatedpids = $post['super_group'];

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product'); 

        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem(); 

        $quote = $quoteItem->getQuote();

        $allItems = $quote->getAllItems();   

        foreach($associatedpids as $key => $val){ 

            if(($product->getId() != $key) && ($val != 0)){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $key,
                    'qty' => $product->getQty(),
                    'options' => $post['options']
                );
                $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($key);
                $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
                $this->_cart->save();
            } 
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional options to order items using observer and it will show everywhere. First need to create events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_load_after">
    <observer name="add_additional_option" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\AddAdditionalOption"/>
</event>
```

After that write below code in observer file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class AddAdditionalOption implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $_request;

public function __construct(
   RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {             
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $additionalOptions = [];
    $additionalOptions[] = array(
        'label' => "Custom Label",
        'value' => "Custom Info",
    );
    $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
}
```

}